# R - subsetting by date

Tags: r, datetime, posixlt

i'm trying to subset a large dataframe by date field ad facing strange behaviour:

1) find interesting time interval:

```
> ld[ld$bps>30000000,]
            Date.first.seen Duration Proto      Src.IP.Addr Src.Pt      Dst.IP.Addr Dst.Pt Tos Packets    Bytes      bps
1400199 2015-03-31 13:52:24    0.008 TCP      3.3.3.3   3128      4.4.4.4  65115   0      39    32507 32500000
1711899 2015-03-31 14:58:10    0.004 TCP      3.3.3.3   3128      4.4.4.7  49357   0      29    23830 47700000
```

2) and try to look whats happening on that second:

```
> ld[ld$Date.first.seen=="2015-03-31 13:52:24",]
            Date.first.seen Duration Proto      Src.IP.Addr Src.Pt      Dst.IP.Addr Dst.Pt Tos Packets    Bytes bps
1401732 2015-03-31 13:52:24   17.436 TCP      3.3.3.3   3128    6.6.6.6  51527   0       3     1608 737
```

don't really understand the behavior - i should get way more results. 
for example

```
> ld[1399074,]
            Date.first.seen Duration Proto      Src.IP.Addr Src.Pt      Dst.IP.Addr Dst.Pt Tos Packets    Bytes      bps
1399074 2015-03-31 13:52:24    0.152 TCP      10.10.10.10   3128    11.11.11.11  62375   0       8     3910   205789
```

for date i use POSIXlt

```
> str(ld)
'data.frame':   2657583 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Date.first.seen: POSIXlt, format: "2015-03-31 06:00:00" "2015-03-31 06:00:00" "2015-03-31 06:00:00" "2015-03-31 06:00:01" ...
...
```

would appreciate any assistance. thanks!

Comment: reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

POSIXlt may carry additional info which is supressed when printing the entire `data.frame`, timezone, daylight savings etc. Have a look at  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/DateTimeClasses.html.

Printing only the POSIXlt variable (`ld$Date.first.seen`) does generally supply at least some of this additional information.

If you're not for some particular reason required to keep your variable in the POSIXlt and if you don't need the extra functionality the format enables, a simple:

```
ld$Date.first.seen = as.character(ld$Date.first.seen)
```

Added before your subset statement will probably solve your problem.